# how to implement a deep integrated APP in android, just like facebook launcher

Tags: android, facebook, android-launcher

Now a days, facebook release a laucher for android platform. That's extremely cool. And i wonder to know how they implements. In my opinions, some feature should be supported by system module, in the other word, facebook should make their own ROM to suppoted their launcher. But it is a independence APP, u can download by Google Player.

I am curious to know which technology was used in FB Launcher~

Comment: We can't tell you how something was done if you don't tell us specifically what you're curious about.  My guess is few to none of us have downloaded this app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the app which you will be able to download from April 12th onwards, Facebook has simply made another Launcher. You can see the SDK sample that comes with the Android SDK to see how that works.

On devices that Facebook has developed in partnership with the manufacturers (only HTC First as of now), the launcher is integrated more deeply into the System than the downloadable app, as it has ROM modifications there as well. Facebook Home on the HTC First will be more feature rich than the downloadable Facebook Home.